# How do I set a VSTemplate on an item type to install across all languages in VS2015?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a generic template file for a "ReadMe.MD" file that I want to have included by all of our development staff. Some of our developers are doing VB projects and others are doing C# or Web.

I have successfully been able to install the template under one language/project type using the following vsTemplate file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>ReadMe.MD</DefaultName>
    <Name>ReadMe.MD</Name>
    <Description>Standard read me file</Description>
    <ProjectType>VisualBasic</ProjectType>
   <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
   <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.MD" ReplaceParameters="false">ReadMe.MD</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

But since this file template is not language dependent how do I get it to install across all of the project types?